# Post Notice Text (PostHistory table) in Data Explorer

Tags: support, data-explorer, data-dump

I am trying to get the post notice text from the `PostHistory` table in Data Explorer. I'm having trouble understanding how exactly to do this.

According to the [database schema](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede), `PostHistoryTypeId` of `33` indicates a post notice being added to a given post. From the column descriptions, I'd imagine that either the `Text` or the `Comment` columns would contain the actual post notice text. However, it seems as though the `Text` field is always blank. In addition, the `Column` field, which seems to contain an ID for use in the `Comments` table, does not lead to a correct post notice text.

For example: see [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/468889/594631/), and the [following query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/468890/594634/).

Am I misunderstanding what the `Comment` field in the `PostHistory` table actually refers to? Is there some other way to get the actual post notice text from the data?